# Trouble adding gifs to jetpack compose using coil

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am new to jetpack compose and I found a way to add a gif to my app using coil but a lot of the code I found seem outdated and not working anymore and I can't find any other useful information . I don't know what to do to make it work.

I found this code on GitHub:

```
@ExperimentalCoilApi
@Composable
fun MessageContents(
    message: Message,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
...
                    val context = LocalContext.current
                    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
                        .componentRegistry {
                            if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
                                add(ImageDecoderDecoder(context))
                            } else {
                                add(GifDecoder())
                            }
                        }
                        .build()
                    Image(
                        painter = rememberImagePainter(
                            imageLoader = imageLoader,
                            data = it.image,
                            builder = {
                                size(OriginalSize)
                            }
                        ),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(top = paddingTop)
                    )
...
```

Comment: 1. `ImageLoader` should be provided via `Application` class
2. Use `AsyncImage` instead of `Image`

Comment: Did you find the solution? @Ofir Lang

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me.

```
@Composable
fun AsyncGIFLoader(url: String) {

    val imageRequest = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(url)
        .decoderFactory(GifDecoder.Factory())
        .crossfade(true)
        .build()

    AsyncImage(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(dimensionResource(R.dimen.dimen_100dp))
            .height(dimensionResource(R.dimen.dimen_100dp)),
        model = imageRequest,
        contentDescription = "GIF"
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncImage` instead of `Image`, it has a `decoderFactory` where you need to specify `GifDecoder.Factory()` for the GIF animation to load and play

```
    import coil.annotation.ExperimentalCoilApi
    import coil.compose.AsyncImage
    import coil.decode.GifDecoder
    import coil.request.ImageRequest
    
    @ExperimentalCoilApi
        @Composable
        fun ImageGif() {
            AsyncImage(
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                    .data("you gif URL")
                    .decoderFactory(GifDecoder.Factory())
                    .build(),
                contentDescription = "descriptionString",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(250.dp)
                    .height(150.dp),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            )
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).